# Offline access to Google Calendar without Chrome

Tags: linux, firefox, google-calendar

I use Firefox. Quite often when I'm offline I accidentally try to add an event to my Google Calendar. This always fails and even worse, I lose the data. Also reading access in Firefox only works in that some pages might happen to be in the cache.

Not being able to add events is generally not so critical as I can simply do this via my phone. However, is there any way to get sane behaviour in Firefox, that is the app should not allow me to try to enter new data while offline?

In addition, I would like to be able to edit my calendar from my (Linux) computer while offline so I'd welcome any suggestions regarding that as well.

Comment: If you dig Mozilla, you can use [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.com/thunderbird/) + [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) for offline access to Google Calendar.

Comment: This question needs to add more add details like showing what was tried and need more focus as it is asking about making Firefox to block Google Calendar when the computer is offline to and how to capture data while offline. Also is uncliear as it's not clear if what kind of app what to use to while being offline or if they are open to use, i.e. an spreadsheet and the Google Calendar API / Google Apps Script to sync the data when be online again.

Comment: I think complaining that a decade-old question that no one even cares about any more does not contain its own answer is a strange hobby, but you do you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official (supported) way to do that at the moment; Chrome is the only browser able to do it.

> The new version of Calendar offline is now only supported for Google Chrome.

[Source](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1340696).

Comment: The major reason this is true is that Google retired much of its "offline" client support ( its likely simply wasn't being used ) several months ago.